# Unauthorized In Microsoft Graph Api Unable To Get Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I am currently developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 site which uses the Microsoft Graph API application to retrieve and insert data into Microsoft Planner. Said site already has Azure Active Directory authentication. I am currently using the following code to get the access token to login into the Graph API application.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
        string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
        Uri authUri = await authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                                                              new Uri(redirectUri), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

        // Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page
        return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        // Get the 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect
        string authCode = Request.Params["code"];

        // The same url we specified in the auth code request
        string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

        // Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);

        TokenCache fileTokenCache = new FilesBasedAdalV3TokenCache("C:\\temp\\justin.bin");
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthorityTenantID, fileTokenCache);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        try
        {
            // Get the token silently first
            authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource, credential);
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthority, fileTokenCache);

            authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
            authCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource);

            return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            // Save the token in the session
            Session["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken;
        }

        return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme));
    }
```

The code above gets the access token without any issue. I am able to get all users of the active directory without any issue and store them in a database. However when I try to get any data relating to a task I keep on getting the following error

```
{  
   StatusCode:401,
   ReasonPhrase:'Unauthorized',
   Version:1.1,
   Content:System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
   Headers:{  
      Transfer-Encoding:      chunked request-id:40      b53d20-c4fc-4614-837b-57a6bebb8d79 client-request-id:40      b53d20-c4fc-4614-837b-57a6bebb8d79 x-ms-ags-diagnostic:{  
         "ServerInfo":{  
            "DataCenter":"North Europe",
            "Slice":"SliceC",
            "Ring":"2",
            "ScaleUnit":"000",
            "Host":"AGSFE_IN_17",
            "ADSiteName":"NEU"
         }
      }      Duration:28.4537      Strict-Transport-Security:      max-age=31536000 Cache-Control:      private Date:Fri,
      07      Dec 2018 14:12:50      GMT Content-Type:application/json
   }
}
```

I have checked azure app and it has full access rights. Any Help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please expand your question to include the actual Graph Api Url you made the call to. Also, do you get the same error if you try this call on the [Graph Explorer] (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) ?

Comment: The Graph url I was using is the following
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/eRe74RmOMEe4KQtwzBOFSZcACBsE

Answer (score 1):

I have a managed to solve my issue. The issue was with Graph Api requiring you to run as delegated account as well as setting the App on azure as a native application.

The Code that was used is as follows

```
        private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string resourceId, string userName, string password)
            {
                try
                    {
                        var authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AuthorizationLoginUri"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
                        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                        var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
                        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientIdNativeClient"], credentials);
                        // Get the result
                        return authResult.AccessToken;
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    // TODO: handle the exception
                    return;
                    }
            }
```

I had found this site https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/microsoft-graph/ that encountered the same issue as me